# How to new line in echo without <br>

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
echo preg_replace("~([a-z.:\])([a-z.0-9]*\/)?([a-z.\?_=]*)([0-9]*)\/~", "", "https://www.example.com/products.php?id=");
}
?>
```

How do you make a new line without `<br>`? I tried `\n` `PHP_EOL` and always get an error.

Comment: `\n` and `PHP_EOL` only add linebreaks when writing to files. If you look at your html source, you'll see they're in there alright. If you want a new line rather than `<br>`, you can use `<p>`. Other than that; is pretty much "it".

Comment: *"i try \n PHP_EOL and always error"* - Show us what you tried then. Yet, that still won't add new lines if you want to "echo" on screen.

Comment: refresh, i edited my code

Comment: where I have to put <p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

w3schools.com offers that way

```
 echo nl2br("Firts Line \n  Second Line");
```

result will be,

```
Firts Line 
Second Line
```

For more details : [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
echo "some string \n";
```